# Use of config.client.version property in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I am working on basic spring cloud config server and client. 
The config client retrieves the properties from server.

I am testing the *live reload feature of actuator* (the one using `@RefreshScope`). It works fine and I could see the changes reflecting from server into client.

Here is the property residing on config server:

```
message=Hello world
```

and I changed it to:

```
message=Hello spring world
```

After changing this property I sent a **POST** call to `http://localhost:8080/actuator/refresh` (my client is on local @ 8080).

For which I got below response (**200 OK**):

```
[
    "config.client.version",
    "message"
]
```

Now I expected the `message` to be there but not `config.client.version`. This seems to be property being used by spring boot internally.

I tried to search but could not find any document stating the use of this property.

Comment: check

 https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/client/ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java

Comment: Looks like if response contains either state or version or both, that property is added.

Comment: If you use Git as backend, this `config.client.version` property will be the Git commit ID. Basically, if the latest commit ID of your Git branch is different after you refresh, this property can indicate it.